# Is there any way to optimise this function?

Tags: python, optimization

I was told to make a program that solves a simple python exercise which should run under 12000ms. I managed to get a working piece of code. However it only works for small numbers passed into the n parameter.

```
def function(n):
    res = [(a, b) for a in range(1, n+1) for b in range(1, n+1) if a*b == sum([i for i in range(1, n+1) if i!=a and i!=b])]
    return res
```

Is there any way to optimise the code so that it runs under 12000ms for large numbers of n (e.g. n=100000)?

### Exercise:

A friend of mine takes the sequence of all numbers from 1 to n (where n > 0).
Within that sequence, he chooses two numbers, a and b.
He says that the product of a and b should be equal to the sum of all numbers in the sequence, excluding a and b.
Given a number n, could you tell me the numbers he excluded from the sequence?
The function takes the parameter: n (n is always strictly greater than 0) and returns an array or a string (depending on the language) of the form:

[(a, b), ...] with all (a, b) which are the possible removed numbers in the sequence 1 to n.

[(a, b), ...] will be sorted in increasing order of the "a".

It happens that there are several possible (a, b). The function returns an empty array (or an empty string) if no possible numbers are found which will prove that my friend has not told the truth! (Go: in this case return nil).

E.g. function(26) should return [(15, 21), (21, 15)]

Comment: So... what's the exercise?

Comment: Get a faster computer?

Comment: Not sure how fast it's gonna make your code but there's no need to create a list here: ```sum([i for i in range(1, n+1) if i!=a and i!=b])``` you can simply ```sum(i for i in range(1, n+1) if i!=a and i!=b)```

Comment: @pyzer: That'll dramatically reduce peak memory usage, and might speed stuff up a little, but doing the `sum` over and over is a massive waste in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a math problem than anything else:

Isolate b:

> a*b = sum - (a+b)
>
> (a+1)*b = sum - a
>
> b = (sum - a)/(a+1)

Now you can substitute b where needed. With b out of the way, you don't have to iterate over the list for each element in it. You can iterate over the list just once, applying the equation for each element.

In fact, you don't even have to go through the whole list. Verifying its first sqrt(sum) elements is enough, as anything bigger than that has to be multiplied by another smaller than that number.

Here is the code:

```
import math
n = 26
valid = []

sum_n = (n+1)*n/2
limit = int(math.sqrt(sum_n)-0.5)
for a in range(1, (limit+1)):
    if (sum_n-a) % (a+1) == 0:  
        valid.append(( a, int((sum_n-a) / (a+1)) ))

if valid:
    if valid[-1][0] == valid[-1][1]:
        valid += [(x, y) for y, x in reversed(valid[:-1])]
    else:
        valid += [(x, y) for y, x in reversed(valid)]

print(valid)
```

And the output:

```
[(1, 175), (3, 87), (7, 43), (10, 31), (15, 21), (21, 15), (31, 10), (43, 7), (87, 3), (175, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sum([i for i in range(1, n+1) if i!=a and i!=b])
```

is pretty easily optimized out. Just put:

```
basesum = sum(range(1, n+1))
```

outside the listcomp, then change the test to:

```
if a*b == basesum - sum({a, b}) # Accounts for possibility of a == b by deduping
```

or if `a==b` is not supposed to be allowed, the even simpler:

```
if a*b == basesum - a - b
```

That instantly reduces the per element work from `O(n)` to `O(1)`, which should cut overall work from `O(n**3)` to `O(n**2)`.

There's other optimizations available, but that's an easy one with a huge impact on big-O runtime.

If I'm reading the prompt correctly, your `a` and `b` are order-insensitive. So if your results can just show `(a, b)` and not `(b, a)` as well, you can replace:

```
for a in range(1, n+1) for b in range(1, n+1)
```

with:

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), 2)
```

or if `a == b` is allowed:

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, n+1), 2)
```

which halves the amount of work to do "for free" (and does more of it at the C layer instead of the Python bytecode layer, which often speeds things up a little more). If you must get the results in both orders, you can post-process to produce the reverse of each non-duplicated pair as well (or be a lazy programmer and use `for a, b in itertools.permutations(range(1, n+1), 2)` or `for a, b in itertools.product(range(1, n+1), repeat=2)` instead of `combinations` or `combinations_with_replacement` respectively, doing most/all of the work of your original nested loop, but shoving more to the C layer so the same theoretical work runs a little faster in practice).

Comment: additionally `sum(range(1,n+1))` is a triangular number and it have a direct formula `n*(n+1)//2`

Comment: @Copperfield: True. I didn't bother to optimize that because once the work is done once instead of per-pair, it's irrelevant to big-O (a single `O(n)` step with a low constant multiplier will be irrelevant next to a `O(n**2)` step with higher constants), but yes, that would save some work.